# Process substitution with input redirection

Tags: bash, io-redirection, file-descriptors, process-substitution

I am trying to understand input redirection in combination with process substituation. I am using `bash` 3

An example with `tr` is the following

```
$ tr "o" "a" <(echo "Foo")
tr: extra operand `/dev/fd/63'
Try `tr --help' for more information.
```

I think I understand why this does not work. The process substitution `<( )` creates a file descriptor, where `tr` only reads from standard input.

How can I make it work with proper redirection?

I know that I could simply use pipes:

```
$ echo "Foo" | tr "o" "a"
Faa
```

However, I am trying to get a better understanding. I tried some thing with the help of `man bash`, by using `<&`, but I don't really know what I am doing.

How can I use process substitution properly using `tr`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You were really close:

```
tr "o" "a" < <(echo "Foo")
```

The substitution `<()` makes a file descriptor and just pastes the path to the shell. For comprehension just execute:

```
<(echo blubb)
```

You will see the error:

```
-bash: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
```

That's why it just pastes `/dev/fd/63` into the shell and `/dev/fd/63` is not excutable, because it's a simple pipe. In the `tr`-example above, it's `echo "Foo"` that writes to the pipe and via input redirection `<` it's the `tr` command that reads from the file descriptor.

Comment: Aah, of course, I did try `<<(` :o. Thanks!

Comment: `ls -ld <(echo blubb)` may be a better illustration.

Answer (score 5):

I found the [Bash One-Liners Explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/) series very useful in understanding more about all this stuff.

Specifically the article linked above is all about input redirection.

To solve the specific example above:

```
> tr "o" "a" <<< $(echo "Foo")
Faa
```

Comment: This is using a "here-string", but does not do any input redirection. Although it is possible on my question, for multi-line input it breaks (as far as I can see from my tests)

Comment: @Bernard. It does redirection. First it runs `echo Foo` in a subshell with its output redirected to a pipe. It reads that output from the other end of the pipe and stores it (minus the trailing newline characters). Once eof is reached on that pipe, depending on the shell, it performs word splitting on that and joins the resulting words with space (`bash`) or not (zsh, ksh93). And then stores that and a newline into a temporary file. Then `tr` input is redirected from that temporary file.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas (was not notified by your remark). I did not know the here-string also uses temporary files, but that makes sense. Thank you.